# Dotnet test coverage always null

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, sonarqube, nunit, coverlet

I have an issue with test coverage. When I run this command

```
dotnet test ../XZrcndee.sln --output ../coverage /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=results\coverage /p:CoverletOutput=..\results\coverage /p:MergeWith=..\results\coverage.json /p:CoverletOutputFormat="opencover"
```

It show me that codecoverage is 0

[image]

When I try run dotnet test in only one project I got the correct result.

```
dotnet test ../XZrcndee.Domain.Tests/XZrcndee.Domain.Tests.csproj --output ../coverage /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=results\coverage /p:CoverletOutput=..\results\coverage /p:MergeWith=..\results\coverage.json /p:CoverletOutputFormat="opencover"
```

[image]

Do I miss somthing?

[image]

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
dotnet test ../XZrcndee.sln --output ../coverage /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=results\coverage /p:CoverletOutput=..\results\coverage /p:MergeWith=..\results\coverage.json /p:CoverletOutputFormat="opencover" /maxcpucount:1
```

make sure to cleanup the "coverage.json" after each run otherwise it will merge results from mulitple runs also.